# How to display a segmented picker with a text and an image below it

Tags: swiftui

I would like to display a segmented picker that shows
its elements as a text and just below it, an image/icon.
The documentation does not mention that this would be impossible.

I've tried a number of ways, but none seem to work. The `VStack` option, shows the text and the image side-by-side (I want text on top and image below) and does not work.
The `Label` options show the text but not the image/icon and does not work.

How can I display a segmented picker that shows its elements as a text and just below it an image.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TestPicker()
    }
}

struct TestPicker: View {
    @State var selection = "fire"
    
    var body: some View {
        Picker("type", selection: $selection) {
            VStack {
                Text("fire")
                Image(systemName: "flame")
            }.tag("fire")
            
            VStack {
                Text("water")
                Image(systemName: "water.waves")
            }.tag("water")
            
            // no picture here
            // Label("fire", systemImage: "flame").tag("fire")
            // Label("water", systemImage: "water.waves").tag("water")
            
            // no picture here
            // Label {Text("fire")} icon: {Image(systemName: "flame")}.tag("fire")
            // Label {Text("water")} icon: {Image(systemName: "water.waves")}.tag("water")
        }
        .pickerStyle(.segmented)
        .frame(width: 222, height: 66)
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot display more than one line in the `segmented` style. You have to create a custom picker from scratch for example described [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/build-swiftui-segmented-customizable-control/).

Comment: thanks, good link with some useful explanations. How come I cannot see these restrictions mentioned in the official Picker docs.
Where do `people` find this type of "real" documentations?

Comment: Many SwiftUI UI elements are based on AppKit/UIKit classes. The segmented Picker is actually `NS/UISegmentedControl` which cannot be customized either. But unlike good old  AppKit/UIKit SwiftUI is flexible enough that you can create whatever you like yourself.

Comment: I need a visual representation of what you are trying to achieve.